# Polymer 1.0 change bind with Javascript in <template> dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I don't know how to edit a bind(variable) from  tag

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ajaxResponse}}">
  <script>
        var temp = {{item.title}};
        //I want to do this
        {{item.title}} = temp.slice(1, 10);
  </script>      
  <google-map-marker latitude="{{item.lat}}" longitude="{{item.lng}}" title="{{item.title}}"> </google-map-marker>
</template>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed).

```
<google-map-marker title="[[updateTitle(item.title)]]"></google-map-marker>
```

If you are inside your own custom element you can just add the function to the element description:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'your-element',
  updateTitle: function (title) {
    return title.slice(1,10);
  }
});
```

Or if you are in a `dom-bind`you can define that function on the `template` element.

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  ...
</template>

<script>
  document.getElementById('app').updateTitle= function (title) {
    return title.slice(1,10);
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change ajax response, it is the best to make it through `on-response` event. 
Little change this

```
<template is="dom-repeat" id="ironList" items="[]">
<google-map-marker latitude="{{item.lat}}" longitude="{{item.lng}}" title="  {{item.title}}"> </google-map-marker>
</template>
```

Then you need to add function to on-response event to iron-ajax element.

```
<iron-ajax on-response="responseFunc"
```

and then describe it func:

```
responseFunc: function(e) {
//receive all response data in array
var items = e.detail.response;
//perform your operations
var item = items[0]; 
var temp = item.title;
item.title = temp.slice(1, 10);
//add you changed data to template
this.$.ironList.push('items', item);
}
```

If you have a lot of arrays in response object, you can easily use a loop.